# Windows Phone 7 C# Device and User Info

Tags: c#, windows-phone, device

Recently I was thinking of a way to confirm the user info inside an app.

Is the typed email, the windows phone live-id of the device?

Is the typed number, the windows phone card-number of the device?

All I know until now is that I can get some info from windows phone SDK.

For DeviceId (hash) I use DeviceEctendedProperties, based on device serial i suppose

For UserId (hash) I use UserExtendedProperties, based on user live id i suppose

And with that we can identify a user and a device.

To get the right info from user like email and phone number you must ask him.
So the question: Is there any way to validate the user entry?

For example:

```
App -> Form - > form_info(email, phone) -> Validate(form_info) -> Success OR Unsuccess
```

For Validate() i was thinking of something like:

```
form_info -> function_hasher() -> form_info_hash -> IF form_info_hash MATCHES with UserId (hash) and UserPhone (hash)
```

If there is a UserPhone hash to match the number of card!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's no way to get this data or even verify that it's right, short of asking the user to email/SMS a particular address/phone number.  If you want to go that route you can use a [SmsComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394005%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or an [EmailComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).